# Is it possible to have Winzip notify a program when it completes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sleep, winzip

I am writing code to zip a large number of files in a single directory into smaller batches of files. The program does everything fine, but if it is zipping thousands and you tell it that you want batches of 10 or 100, it starts a ridiculous number of Winzip windows at once.

I have worked around this slightly in that I have set it to sleep for 4 seconds between starting each zip process, but this is sloppy as it can take well over 4 seconds for larger batches, and noticeably less for smaller batches.

So my question, if asked succinctly, is whether it is possible to be notified in VB when Winzip completes its zipping process, and if so, how?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered .NET 4's in-built zip support as an alternative?

Comment: Yes I have, but it does not compress as well generally. Also, it was requested that this program specifically use Winzip.

Comment: How are you launching WinZip? If you are starting it with [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx), you can `WaitForExit` on the object.

Comment: I was using a Shell command: Shell(ZIP_EXE & " -a " & i & ".zip" & " " & "@" & i & ".txt")

Comment: Why not use the WinZip command line utility?

Comment: Using the System process worked perfectly. Thank you crashmstr.